# How do you empty an array prop when closing a child component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a parent containing a bootstrap table. I use the @row-selected and @row-clicked options to fetch data from the individual table rows.
I am passing the data as a prop to a child component which is a modal.
The data shows up in the modal as expected.

The problem is that when I close the modal, the prop is still populated with the data from when I opened it.
Then when I click on the row a second time, the modal opens again, but the data in the prop gets removed, so I am left with an empty modal.
I need to open the modal a third time to send the data to the prop again.

My guess is that I need to empty the prop when I close the modal. I tried to splice it, but with no luck.

**Parent:**

```
<template>
  <b-container>
    <b-card class="mt-4 mb-4">
      <h5>{{ $t('errorLogs.errorLog') }}</h5>
      <common-table
        :items="items"
        :fields="fields"
        :per-page="[10, 25, 50]"
        selectable
        :select-mode="'single'"
        @row-selected="onRowSelected"
        @row-clicked="showModal"
        include-actions
        sort-desc
      />
    </b-card>

    <error-log-entry-modal ref="myModal" :items="selectedItems"/>

   
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
  import myModal from '@/components/myModal';

  export default {
    components: {
      myModal,
    
    },
    data() {
      return {
        items: null,
        selectedRows: []


      };
    },
    computed: {
      fields() {
        return [
          {
            key: 'name',
            label: name,
          },
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
  
      onRowSelected(fields){
        this.selectedRows = fields
      },

      showModal(){
        if (this.selectedRows) {
          return this.$refs.errorLogEntryModal.show()
        }
      },
    }

  };
</script>
```

**Child:**

```
<template>
  <b-modal
    modal-class="data-modal"
    v-model="myModal"
    ok-only
    size="xl">
    <b-row class="lg-12" v-for="item in selectedItems">
      <b-col class="ml-2 mr-2 mb-4">
        {{ item-name }}
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
    <template #modal-footer>
      <b-button variant="primary" @click="close">Ok</b-button>
    </template>
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    props: {
      selectedItems: Array,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        showModal: false,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      show(){
        this.showModal = true
      },
      close(){
        this.showModal = false
        this.selectedItems.splice(0)
      }
    },
  };
</script>
```

Comment: One thing is, Props are used for one-way binding purposes. You should not try to alter the props' values inside the child components. Try copying the prop value in a data property and performing the operations on that property.

Comment: I don't see how this code ever can work, I think you have things mixed up. In your parent template you have `:items="selectedItems"` as a prop for the child. But you did not define `selectedItems` in data and your child does not have a prop `items`.